# OpenLayers 8.1 apply FlatStyle conditionally

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-8

I am trying to figure out how to apply a FlatStyle to a feature conditionally as I am using WebGL to render my features.

The [API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_flat.html) describes that you can use an array of rules, however I can't find an example of the rules being used.

I have tried to modify the official WebGL points layer [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-points-layer.html) to use the code example from the API, however nothing renders.

My assumption was to pass the array of rules to the style property of the WebGLPointsLayer like so:

```
const rules = [
  {
    filter: ['>', 'population', 1000000],
    style: {
      'circle-radius': 10,
      'circle-color': 'red',
    }
  },
  {
    else: true,
    style: {
      'circle-radius': 5,
      'circle-color': 'blue',
   },
 ];

var pointsLayer = new WebGLPointsLayer({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: rules,
  });
```

This doesn't seem to be the correct way to apply the rules but again, I can't find any example or documentation on how to use them.

Comment: The only example I can find is a test with a regular vector layer https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/test/rendering/cases/vector-style-rules/main.js  Also `'circle-color'` should be `'circle-fill-color'` and `'population'` should be `['get', 'population']`

Comment: It works with regular vector layer https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-points-layer-forked-9s97tl?file=/main.js

Comment: Ah, assumed it had different Syntax as i just took it from the example documentation.
As far as i can tell, it appears that the WebGLPointsLayer/Renderer does not support the new 'rules' for conditional styling. I guess i need a layer for each style then.